# How to get a flags enum to convert to UInt64 with a TypeConverter

Tags: c#, enums, type-conversion, flags, uint64

I have a class which takes a generic class `TState` in its constructor, under the condition that `TState` can be converted to a `UInt64`using a `TypeConverter`. It will then be used as flags.

I want to use a `[Flags]` enum for `TState`, but even if I define it as

```
[Flags]  
public enum EState : ulong
{
    None = 0x0,
    State1= 0x1,
    State2= 0x2,
    State3= 0x4
}
```

then if `TypeConverter typeConv = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(EState));`  `typeConv.CanConvertTo(typeof(UInt64))`is false.

How can I make an enum which will convert appropriately? Thanks!

Comment: How do you define the condition that it must be convertible to `UInt64` in the `where` clause?

Comment: You don't - this is an internal class, and it only works if the condition holds.

Comment: I thought so! I was scratching my head how you do it in the `where` clause. See my response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Convert.ChangeType()`:

```
[Flags]
private enum MyEnum1 : ulong 
{
   A =1,
   B = 2
}
```

And then

```
MyEnum1 enum1 = MyEnum1.A | MyEnum1.B;
ulong changeType = (ulong) Convert.ChangeType(enum1, typeof (ulong));
```

---

### UPDATE

Why `TypeDescriptor` does not work?

According to docs:

> This method looks for the appropriate
>   type converter by looking for a
>   TypeConverterAttribute. If it cannot
>   find a TypeConverterAttribute, it
>   traverses the base class hierarchy of
>   the class until it finds a primitive
>   type.

TypeDescriptor and TypeConvertor work with `ExpandableObjectConverter` while `Convert` works with `IConvertible`.

Comment: Thanks, that works :) As it happens, I can change the internals of the generic class if necessary, so that may be the way to go. But I would still like to know why TypeConverter cannot convert it.

Comment: Also  ulong changeType2 =(UInt64) Convert.ToInt64(enum1);  works.